# SQL Error [920] [42000]: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: oracle

Getting invalid relational operator error in Oracle for below query:

```
SELECT  t1.mxName,  t2.mxName as mxParent, 
  (SELECT  count(*) FROM MATRIX4.mxTNR t3 where v2=t1.mxOid) objCount 
FROM MATRIX4.MXBUSTYPE t1 INNER JOIN MATRIX4.MXBUSTYPE t2 
on t1.mxParent=t2.mxOid 
WHERE t1.mxFlags & 0x2000000 = 0x2000000 OR t1.mxFlags & 0x4000000 = 0x4000000 
order by mxName
```

Comment: `mxFlags & 0x2000000 ....` - there is no & (ampersand) operator in Oracle. Use [BITAND](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions014.htm#SQLRF00612) function to perform bitwise AND on numbers.

Comment: I presume you're looking for the function BITAND: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions014.htm

Comment: @krokodilko I am getting the error as SQL Error [907] [42000]: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
<pre><code>
SELECT t1.mxName,
       t2.mxName AS mxParent,
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM MATRIX4.mxTNR t3
   WHERE v2=t1.mxOid) objCount
FROM MATRIX4.MXBUSTYPE t1
INNER JOIN MATRIX4.MXBUSTYPE t2 ON t1.mxParent=t2.mxOid
WHERE (BITAND(t1.mxFlags, 0x2000000) = 0x2000000
       OR BITAND(t1.mxFlags, 0x4000000) = 0x4000000)
ORDER BY mxName
</pre></code>

Comment: There is no such thing like `0x4000000` in SQL, please read the documentation - [Numeric Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i139891), if you want to use hexadecimal numbers, please use [TO_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm) function and XXXXX format specifier, for example  `TO_NUMBER( '4000000', 'XXXXXXX` )`